# Reformat text file to csv that includes two different delimiter in python

Tags: python, delimiter

I have a text file like the following:

```
A+B,item_1,item_2
C+D,item_3,item_4
E+F+G,item_5,item_6,item_7
```

I was trying to use python to reformat it to a csv file like the following specific order:

```
B,item_1
A,item_2
D,item_3
C,item_4
G,item_5
F,item_6
E,item_7
```

How would I do this in python?

EDITED:

I have tried many different things and below is an example:

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, input_file = argv

with open(input_file) as x:
    text = x.read()
    split_text = re.split('\+|\n|,', text)

def split_list(y)
    half_text  = len(y)/2
    return y[:half], y[half:]

def(split_text)
```

I was trying to split the list different ways then write it out to an output file. But I am not even close to what I wanted to to because of the variability in lists size. So I did not post my trial codes earlier because I wasn't even sure in what way I should approach it. Thanks for reading!

Comment: "I was trying to use python" - how did you try?

Comment: To clarify, please show the code that you have already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly concise way of doing it:

```
import csv
import sys

input_file, output_file = sys.argv[1:3]

with open(input_file, 'rb') as inp_f, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out_f)
    for row in csv.reader(inp_f):
        try:
            csv_writer.writerows(
                item for item in zip(reversed(row[0].split('+')), row[1:]))
        except IndexError:
            print 'bad row encountered', row
            raise
```

Contents of `output_file` afterwards:

```
B,item_1
A,item_2
D,item_3
C,item_4
G,item_5
F,item_6
E,item_7
```

Comment: This works really well! However, when I apply this for my other text file that's much bigger, it through me this error which I don't know why this happens : csv_writer.writerows(item for item in zip(reversed(row[0].split('+')), row[1:]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Sounds like there's a row in your other file that doesn't match the pattern. I've added an exception handler that will print out the offending row when it's encountered. Not sure what you want to do in that case.

Comment: If you want to just ignore the bad row, you could remove the `raise` in the `except` clause I added. If you also don't even want to print the warning message, replace it with `pass` (you must leave something in the clause).

Answer (score 2):

This would be one way to approach it :

```
lines = ["A+B,item_1,item_2","C+D,item_3,item_4"]
f = open("test.txt","w+")

def new_line(line):
    prt = line.strip().split(',')
    f.write(str(prt[0].split('+')[0]) + ',' + str(prt[1]) + '\n')
    f.write(str(prt[0].split('+')[1]) + ',' + str(prt[2]) + '\n')

map(new_line,lines)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the csv module as that takes care of any escaping.
Then it can be implemented pythonically as

```
import csv, sys

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
  writer.writerows(zip(reversed(row[0].split('+')), row[1:]))
```

Works with the updated example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a file called input.csv and the number of fields matches the number of headers

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import csv

file_name='input.csv'

with open(file_name,'rb') as csvfile:
  my_reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
  for row in my_reader:
   row_length=len(row)
   if row_length:
    columns = row[0].split('+')
    num_columns = len(columns)
    for i in range(num_columns):
        print "%s,%s" % (columns[i],row[i+1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my question a little bit because the number of fields actually varies.

Comment: That should still work even with 10 fields, assuming the number of column headers matches the number of values. If they are less, it is just a matter of adding an if statement to make sure you are less than row_length